# Thread.abort() and Thread.join() taking long time in c# windows applications

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my c# windows application,

I have two buttons export and cancel.

In my export button, here i am exporting sql datatable to .csv file.its running under the thread.

```
thrThreadExportProcess = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startExport));
           thrThreadExportProcess.Start();
           thrThreadExportProcess.IsBackground = true;
```

while its exporting process is running, user hits the cancel button here i am aborting the thread,then joining the thread and deleting the exported file.

while its joining Thread, application get hangs up some time then it will run.

my question is why its hangs up some time.

here is the part of the code in cancel button.

```
if (thrThreadExportProcess.IsAlive)
            {
               thrThreadExportProcess.Abort();
               thrThreadExportProcess.Join();
               File.Delete(csvPath);
            }
```

Kindly provide your valuble Suggestions.

Comment: Whats in the thread run point? My suspicion was always that if thats not checking to end quick enough it will wait.. and wait...

Comment: Calling Abort() on a Thread is not recommended anyway. But I think you simply don't have to (shouldn't) Join() it after you do.

Comment: hi BugFinder, i didn't get what you are asking

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Abort` makes no guarantees about anything and should be avoided. Why it hangs in this specific case depends on the code in the `startExport` method.

From [Thread.Abort on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The thread is not guaranteed to abort immediately, or at all. This situation can occur if a thread does an unbounded amount of computation in the finally blocks that are called as part of the abort procedure, thereby indefinitely delaying the abort. To wait until a thread has aborted, you can call the Join method on the thread after calling the Abort method, but there is no guarantee the wait will end.

Here is the documentation on [Create and Terminate Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Thread.Abort() does not immediately terminate the thread while it's in native code (blocking on I/O or network, for instance). It only tells the thread to exit as quickly as possible.

So Thread.Join() basically waits until the thread that you're aborting finished disk/network I/O.

Using Thread.Abort() is really discouraged these days, you should use .NET 4.5's new async methods whenever possible. You also shouldn't use Thread.Join() from a GUI thread.